# Regarding the Build job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, soapui, build-verification-test

When I am running maven goal in Jenkins which runs soap tests which are developed using groovy, whenever there is a test failure then all the other tests are failed without any test execution from job...

The same suite when I run from SOAPUI tests is getting executed irrespective of the status of test either PASS or FAIL.

In short, I can say tests are running absolutely fine as per the expectations but when I run using soap dependency and run from Jenkins tests are not getting executed as per the expectation.

Let me suppose there are 4 tests A, B, C and D

Run from SOAPUI below is the result :

```
A-PASSED
B-FAILED
C-PASSED 
D-PASSED
```

Run from Jenkins job :

```
A-PASSED
B-FAILED
C-FAILED
D-FAILED
```

I tried maven fail safe plugin and surefire plugin and run the below command from Jenkins job but not lucky enough :

```
mvn test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

Please suggest to me what is going wrong?

Comment: I've not tried the groovy scripts in Jenkins. But from my other Jenkins job experience, giving this option. Can you try the option -e at the end of your maven command, in this case on failure it will continue to execute the other test cases. Used in few shell scripts.

Comment: if you have shell access on the build server and find the maven process , then look /proc/$PID/cmdline and see what extra command line options are passed.  If its not that then check for config files

Comment: @SHASHAVALI LADDU did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,
here what I did

- When run the test cases in SoapUI tool carefully check the **SoapUI log in SoapUI
  tool**, because some times **in the tool test case will pass but some
  exception report in soapui log panel** (Like null point exceptions), these exceptions stop the test
  case execution when running same script from jenkins.
- Enable only one test case and disable other test cases then run from
  jenkins from that you can identify the exact failed test case

Also, try to run test on jenkins by unchecked this option
[image]